# python program that counts number of days in months

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a  python program that lets the user input the month by number for example the month of March as 3 and outputs the number of days and that mount

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Is this a school project?

```
def get_days(month):
    days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    return days[(month-1) % 12]
```

---

I didn't consider a leap year since it wasn't mentioned,

but if you need it:

```
def get_days(month, leap=False):
    days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    return days[month-1] if not leap or month != 2 else 29
```

Comment: Will fail when the year is leap

Comment: @rcvaram True. Added some more stuff  for a leap year.

Comment: Commonly it works, I upvote it

Comment: what's the point of using modulo in the first example? Can you just do days[month-1]?

Comment: this will work if you know its a leap year, but it's not just year%4, just FYI

Comment: @B.Hoffman You can. It looks like ,for some weird reason, I assumed 13+ could be an input.